# How to wrap readline from stdin to use in pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am writing a script to process the output of a program in the console. The program produces huge amounts of results and I want to filter them on the fly in order to only keep what I need.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const {pipeline, Transform} = require('stream');
var readline = require('readline');

class FilterBlastOutput extends Transform {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }

    _transform(chunk,encoding,callback) {
        if(chunk === '\u0003')
            process.exit();
        let row = chunk.split("\t");
        if(row[3] >= 19 && row[4] <= 1) 
            callback(null,chunk);
    }
}

// Added after suggestion to use readline module
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

pipeline(
        process.stdin,
        new FilterBlastOutput(),
        process.stdout,
        err => {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Pipeline failed: ");
            } else {
                console.log('Pipeline succeeded.')
            }
        }
);
```

In pipeline(..) I use process.stdin.
Instead of process.stdin I would like to get a stream providing the data in defined chunks (line).
How can I do that?

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: If you want to create a stream for reading data from a fille, use 'fs.createreadstream'

Comment: Node.js has a built-in [readline](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/readline.html) module

Comment: OK, so I added readline. How to put it into the pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Readline** example (without transform stream):

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin
});

rl.on('line', filterBlastOutput)

function filterBlastOutput(line) {
  let row = line.split("\t");
  if(row[3] >= 19 && row[4] <= 1);
    process.stdout.write(line);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to work with `pipeline`, use [split2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split2):

```js
const {pipeline, Transform} = require('stream');
const split2 = require('split2');

class FilterBlastOutput extends Transform {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }

    _transform(chunk,encoding,callback) {
        if(chunk === '\u0003')
            process.exit();
        let row = chunk.split("\t");
        if(row[3] >= 19 && row[4] <= 1) 
            callback(null,chunk);
    }
}

pipeline(
        process.stdin,
        split2(),
        new FilterBlastOutput(),
        process.stdout,
        err => {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Pipeline failed: ");
            } else {
                console.log('Pipeline succeeded.')
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that option. I would like to use a pipeline instead of this construct.

Answer (score 0):

`pipeline` [accepts a function](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-options) which receives the source as an argument and expects it to return a promise or async iterator, and the `Interface` object returned by `Readline.createInterface` [can be used as an async iterator](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator), so you can do this:

```js
import { pipeline } from "node:stream";
import { createInterface } from "node:readline";

pipeline(
  process.stdin,
  (input) => createInterface({ input }),
  process.stdout,
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
    }
  }
);
```

You could also wrap it to make it easier to reuse/setup options:

```js
import { pipeline } from "node:stream";
import { createInterface } from "node:readline";

function createReadlineIterator(options = { crlfDelay: Infinity }) {
  return (input) => createInterface({
    input,
    ...options
  });
}

pipeline(
  process.stdin,
  createReadlineIterator(),
  process.stdout,
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
    }
  }
);
```